# RPA C# - Process developments in C #

Tags: c#, automation, visual-studio, artificial-intelligence

In my company, we are developing a process to pass data from Siebel and from Topace; the processing of the data that we extract is complex and we want to use our bespoke library written in C#.

Can you recommend any tool compatible with these applications and that can be programmed 100% in C # ? Or at least programmable from C#?

We have already tested Automation Anywhere and Uipath and they do not work.

Any recommendation? I have been told about Blueprism but I can not find a free trial version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our company we use RPA Suite. an A.I able to interact with the graphical interfaces of the applications and fully programmable from C#, Java, Visual Basic, Python, Javascript ... all languages compatible with Windows. 
If you want to work with C#, Rpa Suite for Visual Studio is the only tool that is developed 100% from C#, you do not have to invoke it.

Comment: Could you give me more information about this tool? Do they have a free version?

Comment: The RPA Suite for Visual Studio extension is free and can be downloaded from the Microsoft Visual Studio store at (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rigel-Technoligies.RPAVS) and from "Add extensions" menu of Microsoft Visual Studio. The full version can be downloaded at (http://www.rigeltechnologies.net/tienda-rpa/), there is a free version. With RPA for Visual Studio,you can develop RPA processes entirely in Visual Studio. You can check this introduction (https://youtu.be/gAa6DxIbSmA). In this other video you can see how the extension works (https://youtu.be/-tDwGBoqopw)

Comment: Is it really an ActiveX component? That's old technology, eh?